# html file not returning in the Rest API and return the file name only like 'index' in the screen for the following code when used @RestController

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

html file not returning in the Rest API and return the file name only like 'index' for the following code when used @RestController and working fine only for @Controller.
Here I am using spring boot REST application and index.html with bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

If you know **REST web services** then you must know the fundamental difference between a REST API and a web application i.e. the response from a web application is generally view (HTML + CSS) because they are intended for human viewers.

**REST API** just returns data in form of JSON or XML because most of the REST clients are programs. This difference is also obvious in the @Controller and @RestController annotation.

```
@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody
```

When you use `@Controller` annotation then it corresponds to MVC workflow in Spring Boot and it renders the view. The key difference is that you do not need to use `@ResponseBody` on each and every handler method once you annotate the class with `@RestController`.

`@ResponseBody` is a Spring annotation which binds a method return value to the web response body. It is not interpreted as a view name. It uses HTTP Message converters to convert the return value to HTTP response body, based on the content-type in the request HTTP header. The content type can be JSON or XML.

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behaviour of `@RestController`. The main difference between `@RestController` and `@Controller` is `@RestController` will by-pass the view resolution but `@Controller` will not.

Technically , it is due to the presence of the `@ResponseBody` of the `@RestController`.  `@ResponseBody` will enable [`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5ad261228da962d21195e0995c30cc2bcbf302b8/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java#L178) to process the result return from the `@RestController` method and it will mark that the request has been fully handled within the controller method and by-pass the view resolution process (see [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5ad261228da962d21195e0995c30cc2bcbf302b8/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer.java#L253)).